# python text to speech using pyttsx

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyttsx

I want to use my raspberry pi to announce some text. i have installed pyttsx but not able to use it.i am using python2.7

my program:

```
import pyttsx
engine= pyttsx.init()
engine.setProperty('rate',70)
voices=engine.getProperty('voices')
for voice in voices:
    print "Using voice:", repr(voice)
    engine.setProperty('voice',voice.id)
    engine.say("Hello Hello Hello")
engine.runAndWait()
```

but i am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/announce.py", line 2, in <module>
engine= pyttsx.init()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyttsx-1.1-     py2.7.egg/pyttsx/__init__.py", line 39, in init
eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyttsx-1.1- py2.7.egg/pyttsx/engine.py", line 45, in __init__
 self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyttsx-1.1-p   y2.7.egg/pyttsx/driver.py", line 64, in __init__
  self._module = __import__(name, globals(), locals(), [driverName])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyttsx-1.1-py2.7.egg/pyttsx/drivers/espeak.py", line 19, in <module>
   import _espeak
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyttsx-1.1-py2.7.egg/pyttsx/drivers/_espeak.py", line 24, in <module>
   dll = cdll.LoadLibrary('libespeak.so.1')
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
   self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libespeak.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You have to install the linux package `python-espeak` too. (`sudo apt-get install python-espeak`)

Comment: Thank you sir .now its work fine @ sebastian stigler

Answer (score 49):

It's because you don't have `espeak` installed on your system.
That's why it is giving error

> libespeak.so.1 error: no such file or directory found.

Try to install espeak using:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install espeak
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Ubuntu or another Debian-based distro, Use this

```
sudo apt install libespeak1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one::
Run on Ubuntu/Linux Terminal,

1.`pip install pyttsx3`  ,

2.`sudo apt install libespeak1`

You must have successfully installed.

Answer (score -2):

I'm connecting to Kali through xrdp using Microsoft Remote Desktop on MACOS 10.11 El Capitain and I was having trouble getting pyttsx3 to pick up the driver for the xrdp audio (xrdp sink) in python 3.11.  This was the best answer that googs had and it resolved my issue:

```
sudo apt install libespeak1
```

Comment: This has already been posted in two other answers.