# I have a problem with pyttx3. what should i do?

Tags: python, pip, text-to-speech, pyttsx, pyttsx3

Ubuntu is installed on my laptop.

---

```
import pyttsx3
engine=pyttsx3.init()
engine.say('Sa1lly sells seashells by the seashore.')
```

---

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/shohruz/Desktop/Development/solo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shohruz/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/weakref.py", line 131, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shohruz/Desktop/Development/solo.py", line 2, in <module>
    engine=pyttsx3.init()
  File "/home/shohruz/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "/home/shohruz/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "/home/shohruz/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/shohruz/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/espeak.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import _espeak, toUtf8, fromUtf8
  File "/home/shohruz/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/_espeak.py", line 18, in <module>
    dll = cdll.LoadLibrary('libespeak.so.1')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 451, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libespeak.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

---

1.That is the problem. Please help me...

2. I have installed pyttx3 with `sudo pip install pyttsx3` command.

---

I have installed both 2 versions of pyttsx. pyttsx and pyttsx3. But when i changed pyttsx3 to pyttsx the "no module named 'engine'" error will appear.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499491/python-text-to-speech-using-pyttsx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python text to speech using pyttsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499491/python-text-to-speech-using-pyttsx)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("Sa1lly sells seashells by the seashore")
engine.runAndWait()
```

This  is  under windows but should  not  make any difference
or try this  it works  on my site

Version used:

```
Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```